# filter text in listview android

Tags: java, android

I have a one EditText and one ListView. Item in ListView contains two TextView's. I need to filter ListView if the user enters something in EditText. My adapter:

```
public class AdapterUserIsp extends ArrayAdapter{

public static ArrayList<ItemUserIsp> data = new ArrayList<ItemUserIsp>();
Context context;
int ch = 0;

public static TextView header4;
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")  
public AdapterUserIsp(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<ItemUserIsp> arr) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, arr);
    if (arr != null) {
        data = arr;
    }
    this.context = context;

    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int num) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return data.get(num);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return arg0;
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public View getView(int i, View someView, ViewGroup arg2) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    if (someView == null) {
        someView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_user_isp, arg2, false);
    }

    TextView header1 = (TextView) someView.findViewById(R.id.tvUserNameIsp);
    TextView header2 = (TextView) someView.findViewById(R.id.tvUserPositionIsp);
    header1.setText(data.get(i).header1); 
    header2.setText(data.get(i).header2); 

    return someView;
}

}
```

My activity:

```
final ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.users);
    final AdapterUserIsp adapter = new AdapterUserIsp(this,R.id.users,data);
final EditText search= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.search);
    search_isp.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            lv.invalidateViews();
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

But it don't work. Why? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

insert the following line after lv.invalidateViews(); on onTextChanged method.

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and also you have to implement your adapter class from Filterable if you want to override the filter method.

if adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); doesn't work, do not use final for adapter, get adapter inside the onTextChanged  and after filter your text.

```
YourAdapterOrWhateverAdapter adapter = (YourAdapterOrWhateverAdapter) listView.getAdapter();  
adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

NOTE: This is just guess..

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your adapter.

If you just add some new items to your list arr you have to call:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

If you want to redraw all items you could set the adapter again:

```
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: When i entered something my ListView does not react

Comment: could you post what you entered? Otherwise I just can guess what you did :)